# Calling Retrofit returns null

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

So I have quite a few model classes in my project and have a singleton class which makes Retrofit calls to convert between the model classes. The method `getUsersFromChats` in that class takes in an array of `Chat` model objects, converts each object to a `User` model object, and adds them to a public ArrayList of `User` objects.

Code:

```
//These are instantiated in another method and are not null.
public static ArrayList<User> users;
private static int index;

public void getUsersFromChats(Chat[] chats) {

        if (index < chats.length) {

            Call<UserResponse> getUser = AuthRetrofitClient
                    .getInstance()
                    .getAuthApi()
                    .getUserById(chats[index].getUserID());


            getUser.enqueue(new Callback<UserResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<UserResponse> call, Response<UserResponse> response) {

                    if (response.isSuccessful()) {

                        UserResponse ur = response.body();
                        Log.i("User", ur.getUser().getName());
                        users.add(ur.getUser());
                        Log.i("List", users.toString());

                        index++;
                        getUsersFromChats(chats);

                    } else {
                        try {
                            String errorBody = response.errorBody().string();
                            int index = errorBody.indexOf("\"message\":");

                            if (index != -1) {

                                String errorSub = errorBody.substring(index + 10);
                                //errorBody = errorSub.substring(1, errorSub.length() - 2);
                            }

                            Toast.makeText(context, errorBody, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<UserResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                    Log.i("Didn't work", t.toString());
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

I have an Activity which calls that method after getting an array of `Chat` objects from a Retrofit call and tries to save ArrayList from the singleton class to a local `User` objects ArrayList.

```
Call<ChatListResponse> getAllContacts = ChatRetrofitClient
                    .getInstance()
                    .getChatAPI()
                    .loadChats(SharedPrefManager.getInstance(ChatActivity.this).getUser().getToken());

            getAllContacts.enqueue(new Callback<ChatListResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<ChatListResponse> call, Response<ChatListResponse> response) {

                    if(response.isSuccessful()){

                        ChatListResponse clr = response.body();

                        if(clr.getChats() == null || clr.getChats().length < 1)
                            createChat();

                        else{

                            for(Chat c: clr.getChats())
                                Log.i("Testing", c.getUserID());

                            ConvertFieldsToUserObjects.getInstance(ChatActivity.this).getUsersFromChats(clr.getChats());
                            ArrayList<User> users = ConvertFieldsToUserObjects.users;

                            Log.i("Testing", users.toString());

                            for(User u: users)
                                Log.i("Testing", u.getId());

                            Log.i("Testing", person.getId());

                            if(users.contains(person)){

                                int i = users.indexOf(person);
                                chat = clr.getChats()[i];
                                Toast.makeText(ChatActivity.this, chat.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
```

However, this code doesn't work and the local ArrayList is always empty even though the `Chat` objects list obtained from the Call contains elements. Does this have something to do with the Retrofit calls being asynchronous or is it something else? (The API's, RetrofitClients, and the Response objects work fine as far as I have tested.)

Comment: What  local ArrayList  you mean? You mean `users` is empty?

Comment: Yes, the ArrayList `users` that I instantiate in the `getAllContacts` call is empty.

Comment: What is the output for this line? `Log.i("Testing", users.toString());`

Comment: It's empty. I added the String "Users list" to the message to help identify it.     
`I/Testing: Users list []`

Comment: why you not putting braces for `for loop`?

Comment: My bad, I just have a habit of making one line commands within for loops not use braces. I can change it if you want.

Comment: you want them in loop right ? If yes you need to add the braces, otherwise the result will be different.

Comment: Do you mean the result of the Log messages?

Comment: Let me confirm few things:

 ```for(Chat c: clr.getChats())
Log.i("Testing", c.getUserID());
ConvertFieldsToUserObjects.getInstance(ChatActivity.this).getUsersFromChats(clr.getChats());
ArrayList<User> users = ConvertFieldsToUserObjects.users;
```

Comment: you getting stuck in this part? Did you get value for `c.getUserID()`?

Comment: Yes I got the value for `c.getUserID()` for each chat in the Array of chats. I'm pretty sure the error is in the method `getUsersFromChats` because before calling that, nothing is null.

Comment: print out `chats[index].getUserID()` in `getUsersFromChats`. What you get?

Comment: Yes, it returns the ID of the User for each chat. Also, within that method, the User is not null and the `ArrayList users` for the singleton class gets updated each time (proved by the Log messages).